# Как удалить повторяющиеся записи или объединить в массив связанные

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-framework-2, zend-framework-3

Как удалить дублирующиеся объекты из результата запроса к БД (Zend-Db) или объединить в массив объекты записи из таблицы `auth_roles`

```
$adapter = $this->userTableGateway->getAdapter();

$sql = new Sql($adapter);

$select = $sql->select();
$select->from(['au' => 'auth_users']);
$select->join(['aur' => 'auth_users_roles'], 'au.id = aur.user_id', [], $select::JOIN_INNER);
$select->join(['ar' => 'auth_roles'], 'ar.id = aur.role_id', ['roles' => 'name'], $select::JOIN_INNER);

$statement = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$result = $statement->execute();

if ($result instanceof ResultInterface && $result->isQueryResult()) {
    $resultSet = new HydratingResultSet(new ReflectionHydrator, new User());
    $resultSet->initialize($result);

    return $resultSet;
}
return [];
```

Сейчас получаю 3 записи, так как 2 записи из одной таблицы имеют связь через промежуточную таблицу с тремя записями другой таблицы (ManyToMany).
(т.е. одна запись из таблицы `auth_users` может быть связана с несколькими записями из таблицы `auth_roles`). В результатах первая и третья запись - дубликаты

```
object(AdminUserModule\Model\User)[413]
    private 'id' => string '1' 
    private 'name_first' => string 'Name1'
    private 'name_middle' => string 'Name2'
    private 'name_last' => string 'Name3'
    private 'email' => string 'admin@mail.ru'
    private 'password' => string '123456' 
    private 'roles' => string 'Администратор'
    private 'updated_at' => null
    private 'created_at' => string '2018.03.06 10:03:33'
object(AdminUserModule\Model\User)[424]
    private 'id' => string '2'
    private 'name_first' => string 'Name100'
    private 'name_middle' => null
    private 'name_last' => null
    private 'email' => string 'manager@mail.ru'
    private 'password' => string '123456'
    private 'roles' => string 'Менеджер по продажам'
    private 'updated_at' => null
    private 'created_at' => string '2018.03.06 10:03:32'
object(AdminUserModule\Model\User)[425]
    private 'id' => string '1'
    private 'name_first' => string 'Name1'
    private 'name_middle' => string 'Name2'
    private 'name_last' => string 'Name3'
    private 'email' => string 'admin@mail.ru'
    private 'password' => string '123456'
    private 'roles' => string 'Менеджер по продажам'
    private 'updated_at' => null
    private 'created_at' => string '2018.03.06 10:03:33'
```

Если использую `$select->group('id')`, то дублирующаяся запись пропадает, но остается только первая связь в таблицей `auth_roles`.

Хотелось бы:

```
object(AdminUserModule\Model\User)[413]
    private 'id' => string '1'
    private 'name_first' => string 'Name1'
    private 'name_middle' => string 'Name2'
    private 'name_last' => string 'Name3'
    private 'email' => string 'admin@mail.ru'
    private 'password' => string '123456'
    private 'roles' => array{
        object(AdminUserModule\Model\Roles)[424]
            private 'id' => string '2'
            private 'name' => string 'Name1'
            private 'description' => null
        object(AdminUserModule\Model\Roles)[424]
            private 'id' => string '3'
            private 'name' => string 'Name2'
            private 'description' => null
    }
    private 'updated_at' => null
    private 'created_at' => string '2018.03.06 10:03:33'
object(AdminUserModule\Model\User)[424]
    private 'id' => string '2'
    private 'name_first' => string 'Name100' 
    private 'name_middle' => null
    private 'name_last' => null
    private 'email' => string 'manager@mail.ru' 
    private 'password' => string '123456'
    private 'roles' => string 'Менеджер по продажам'
    private 'updated_at' => null
    private 'created_at' => string '2018.03.06 10:03:32'
```

Comment: Первый вопрос, который хотелось бы прояснить: Какую именно версию фреймворка вы используете? Второе, что хотелось бы заметить, если вы не можете составить нативный запрос sql, который вам вернет то, что вы хотите, то вряд ли вам поможет в этом фреймворк. Сам я для 2 и 3 версий использую Doctrine 2. И не скажу, что силен в зендовой либе, кроме того в доке на эту тему явно указано использовать что-то более лучшее.

Comment: Я использую ZF3 + Doctrine 2, но хотел попрактиковаться с Zend-Db. С составлением запросов у меня действительно имеются сложности. Поэтому решил спуститься на уровень ниже.

Comment: Прекрасное сочетание. Если вы хотите перейти на низкоуровневые запросы - посмотрите в сторону DBALQueryBuilder. Прекрасный построитель запросов. Не лишен, конечно, минусов доктрины (нет поддержки union, например). + есть совсем простая возможность писать нативный sql запрос.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!